# Bound of matrix with singular values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

Let $A$ be a square matrix and $P$ be a semi positive-definite. Does the following inequality hold?
\begin{equation}
\sigma_{min}(A)P\preceq A^TPA\preceq\sigma_{max}(A)P,
\end{equation}
where $\sigma_{max}(A)$, $\sigma_{min}(A)$ are the maximum and minimum singular values of A.

Thank you

Comment: what is a singular value?

Comment: Singular values of a square matrix $A$ are the root square of eigen values of $A^TA$.